# Google Sync backs up non-media files

Tags: google-drive, google-sync, google-photos

Google Backup and Sync on my Mac is configured to only sync photos and videos.

Yet I see it made a backup of “photos.db” and “store.cloudphotodb” from Apple Photos, among other things.

I only want to use Google Photos, and not clog my Google Drive ...